# Why Mobilefirst 7.1 cannot auto recover / reconnect after network got lost / disconnected

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

IBM MobileFirst 7.1 is not auto recovering after a network failure / lost of connection even though all services/connections are back to normal.

We have a clustered / farm setup with 2 web and app servers (Tomcat). Both app servers are able to serve incoming transactions. We have this incident where-in there is a network failure/lost connection and during that time, all transactions are pointing to 1 app server. Although all connections went back to normal, this 1 app server still unable to connect to the configuration DB. What we did is turn-off this failure server and try the app which is now pointing to the other app server and the app works. We tried to restart the failure app server, test the app and is now accepting transactions. The question is, why it does not auto recover and Tomcat service needs to be restarted? Is MobileFirst 7.1 designed/built in such behavior (not auto recover)?

The expectation is, it should auto recover.

Please help and advise what can be checked/adjusted.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

The default DB configuration (datasource configuration) provided with MFP is not designed to auto recover when there is a DB connectivity issue. You
should be able to configure the MFP for auto-reconnect by providing correct data source configuration. See an article on how this is done for different app servers : https://www.techpaste.com/2016/04/jndi-autoreconnect-java-application-servers/

Comment: Thank you for the response. We will try this and test. I'll let you know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: We tried the suggested configuration in context.xml on this link https://www.techpaste.com/2016/04/jndi-autoreconnect-java-application-servers/ but still not able to auto-recover when the DB server is down for 3 hours and up. Our test scenario is shutdown the server for 15mins, 30mins, 1 hr and all these able to auto-recover. The issue will occur if the server will be down for more than 3 hours. 
Any other configuration that we can check? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to post this in some tomcat forum. May be they have a max limit of 3 hours after that the auto connect might not be working. MFP entirely depend on the underlaying App Server and these settings are from App Server

Comment: Thanks. We'll check on that. For now, our work-around is to put an alert on our monitoring tool for such cases and do the manual restart of Tomcat service.